# Is there a way to join a server/get it's invite through it's ID with the help of your bot?(the bot in this case is already in the server)

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

My bot is in some servers that I'm not in, and I want to join those servers with the help of my bot.

I tried `get_invite(url)` but it looks like it only gets invites from discord.gg, which is not what I'm looking for.

I got the guild ID, now what?

```
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def mycmd(ctx):
    guild = bot.get_guild(521738684803055636)
```

I'm using Discord.py rewrite 1.0.0a.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, use [create_invite()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html?highlight=invite#discord.abc.GuildChannel.create_invite)

It should look something like this

```
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def mycmd(ctx):
    channel = ctx.channel
    invite = await channel.create_invite()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def link(ctx):
    server = client.get_server("server_id")
    link = client.create_invite(destination=server,xkcd=True,max_age=0,max_uses=number)
    await client.say(link)
    #max_age=0-> Never expire link
    #max_uses-> limit to usage the link
    #xkcd-> The URL fragment used for the invite if it is human readable.
```